# How do I only have to input data once?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am currently using the regexp_subtr function to take a string of data (user input) and convert it into a list. Is there a way I can make it so I don't have to input the data twice. This is what I currently have:

```
select regexp_substr((WITH X AS (SELECT ('&EmployeeID') a FROM DUAL) SELECT REPLACE(X.a,' ',',') FROM X),'[^,]+', 1, level) "Employee" 
from dual
connect by regexp_substr ((WITH X AS (SELECT ('&EmployeeID') a FROM DUAL) SELECT REPLACE(X.a,' ',',') FROM X),'[^,]+', 1, level) 
is not null;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can clean it up a bit like this:

```
WITH X AS 
  (SELECT REPLACE('&EmployeeID',' ',',') a FROM DUAL)
select regexp_substr(X.a,'[^,]+', 1, level) "Employee" 
from X
connect by regexp_substr(X.a,'[^,]+', 1, level) is not null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using xmltable with `tokenize`:

```
select * 
from xmltable('tokenize(replace(.," ",","),",")'
              passing '&EmployeeID'
              columns s varchar2(100) path '.');
```

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=19ab9c444502f6e1fd3bdaa44e04ab27): https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=19ab9c444502f6e1fd3bdaa44e04ab27

Answer (score 1):

It appears your client is sqlplus, where the ampersand ('&') is an indication to the client to prompt for user input.  You can avoid being re-prompted for the same variable by adding a second ampersand in front of the variable name.

```
select regexp_substr((WITH X AS (SELECT ('&&EmployeeID') a FROM DUAL) SELECT REPLACE(X.a,' ',',') FROM X),'[^,]+', 1, level) "Employee" 
from dual
connect by regexp_substr ((WITH X AS (SELECT ('&&EmployeeID') a FROM DUAL) SELECT REPLACE(X.a,' ',',') FROM X),'[^,]+', 1, level) 
is not null;
```